# OrientDB Indexing Date

Tags: indexing, orientdb, nosql

I have many BETWEEN date operations within my OrientDB and I want to improve the speed of the execution time with an index. Can you recommend an index type for date queries?

query example:

`select from Install where Installtime between '2016-06-15 00:00:00'  and '2016-06-16 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using SB-Tree NOTUNIQUE Index:

`CREATE INDEX timeindex ON Install (Installtime) NOTUNIQUE`

For more information see [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Indexes.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, thats improved the query speed alot. Whats about the NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX? Is this index type also possible?

Comment: It does not support range queries.